# Kummer map and cohomology group for an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E=E_q$ be the Tate ellipitc curve over a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for a $q$. Let $T$ be its p-adic Tate module. Let $\mathfrak m$ be the maximal ideal in $K$. I saw in this [paper](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-coates/kobayashi.pdf) (page 571, second paragraph) the following claim

> By the Kummer map, we regard $\hat{E}(\mathfrak m)$ as a subgroup of $H^1(K,\, T)$.

Here $\hat{E}(\mathfrak m)$ sits injectively inside $E(K)$. So I tried to show that $E(K)$ sits as a subgroup in $H^1(K,\, T)$. I don't know what exactly the Kummer map is, but I proceeded as following (produced below) to get $E(K) \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_p$ (***not*** $E(K)$) as a subgroup of $H^1(K,\, T)$. Since $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, by Tate's uniformization I know how $E(K)$ looks like. And from the structure of $E(K)$, it follows that $E(K)$ ***doesn't*** sit inside injectively inside $E(K) \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_p$.

So my question is, is there any other way of embedding $E(K)$ inside $H^1(K,\, T)$ that I fail to see?

The details of my calculations:
Start with the Kummer exact sequence:
$$
0 \rightarrow E(\overline{K})[p^n] \rightarrow E(\overline{K}) \xrightarrow{[p^n]} E(\overline{K}) \rightarrow 0
$$
The long exact exact sequence gives the following inclusion 
$$
E(K)/p^nE(K) \hookrightarrow H^1(K, E(\overline{k})[p^n])
$$
Taking the inverse limit gives
$$
\varprojlim_n E(k)/p^nE(K) \hookrightarrow \varprojlim_m H^1(K,E(\overline{K})[p^n]) \cong H^1(k, \varprojlim_{n} E(\overline{K})[p^n]) \cong H^1(K, \varprojlim_n E(\overline{K})[p^n])=H^1(K,\,T)
$$
Since $E(K)$ is Noetherian, $\varprojlim_n E(k)/p^nE(K) \cong E(K) \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_p$ so $E(K) \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_p$ sits inside $H^1(K,\,T)$.

On the other hand, to see that $E(K)$ does not sit inside $E(K) \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_p$ we observe that $E(K)$ is isomorphic to $K^\times/q^\mathbb{Z}$ and $K^\times$, by proposition 5.7 of chapter 2 of Neukirch, has a direct summand of $\mathbb{Z}/{(p^f-1)\mathbb{Z}}$ which gets killed under the tensor product by $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Two things. First, be careful—Tate's theorem holds geometrically only for curves with multiplicative reduction, and holds rationally only for those with  split multiplicative reduction! Also, you're not using the full-strength. The key fact is that $\widehat{E}(\mathfrak{m})$ has NO $p^n$-torsion (for any $n$).

Comment: @Alex: This is about the exceptional zero conjecture, so the setup assumes that $E$ has split multiplicative reduction. And the key fact is that $\widehat{E}(\mathfrak{m})$ has no $\ell$-torsion for $\ell \neq p$ (in fact it can have $p$-primary torsion for a general local field, just not over $\mathbf{Q}_p$.)

Comment: @BrandonCarter Thank you :P I misspoke.

Comment: @BrandonCarter: Excuse my ignorance, but how will $\hat{E}(\mathfrak m)$ having no $\ell$-torsion help? Because I'm talking of torsion part of $E(K)$. I think you are suggesting that I take a new sequence $0 \rightarrow E(\overline{\mathfrak m})[p^n] \rightarrow E(\overline{\mathfrak m}) \xrightarrow{[p^n]} E(\overline{\mathfrak m}) \rightarrow 0$? But is the $[p^n]$ map surjective in this case? How do I see it? Thank you!

Comment: @Sameer: The point is that while $E(K)$ doesn't inject into $E(K) \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p$, the subgroup $\widehat{E}(\mathfrak{m})$ does. This is because tensoring with $\mathbf{Z}_p$ kills the prime-to-$p$ torsion in $E(K)$, but the formal group doesn't contain any such torsion.